# PHP Complex If Else Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and it has code like this:

```
<?php  
    if (is_user_logged_in())   {   
?>
```

I want to add to it another set of `if` statements that check for a variable. I don't know the correct syntax but in plain English I want to say, "if users are logged in *and* $string1 *or* $string2 is empty…"

Please assist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && (empty($string1) || empty($string2)) ) {
```

if you need only one string to be empty but not both. use

```
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && (empty($string1) ^ empty($string2)) ) {
```

Comment: I dont even know what the heck the ^ does in PHP. Please explain. Is that xor?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (user_is_logged_in() AND (strlen($str1) == 0 OR strlen($str2) == 0))
```

I will note that this will work if BOTH str1 and str2 have a zero length. If the variables may not be set, as opposed to having zero length use isset instead of strlen() == 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (user_logged_in() && (empty($string1) || empty($string2))
```

This requires the user_logged_in() call to return true.  At least one of $string1 or $string2 needs to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

`<?php if(is_user_logged_in() && (empty($string1) || empty($string2))) ?>`

Good luck :)